# Compile a java 1.6 project using external library which was build using Java 1.8

Tags: java, compilation, javac, java-6, underscore-java

I have a large project which is build using Java 1.6 and I can not update its build path to Java 1.8 because it causes too many compile errors.

I have to use an external library (underscore) https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javadev/underscore/1.73 which is build using Java 1.8 and it seems it is not backwards compatible.

When I try to compile I get the following error for a sample code:

```
import com.github.underscore.lodash.U;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    U.xmlToJson("foo")
}
```

I get the following errors:

**cannot access com.github.underscore.lodash.U bad class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0.
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.**

The runtime can be 1.6 or 1.8 it is not problem, the main problem is the compile process fails.

Comment: You need to use at least Java 8 to compile your entire project, otherwise it will not be able to recognize class files compiled with Java 8. That said: Java 6 is 16 years old and unsupported, and Java 8 is 8 years old at this point, with minimal support. Consider switching to Java 17 (LTS) or 18, or failing that, 11 (also LTS).

Comment: yes, it seems the only way. but I am confused: I got this error when compile using javac or ant scripts. But on eclipse, I generated a dummy project which has jdk 1.6.45 as jre system library in the build path and project compilance is 1.6. I add the external jar (unerscore) and write a simple call as stated in the question above  and it compiles fine?

Comment: Eclipse has its own compiler called `ecj`, perhaps it's a higher Java version than your JRE?

Comment: prject properties/java build path/has two entires: the underscore and JRE Sysem library 1.6.45 which is set as alternate JRE. Maybe eclipse ecj can handle it different than javac even if it is using 1.6?

Comment: Right-click your project, go to Properties, and check under Java Compiler (not Build Path). I'm guessing your compliance level is set higher than Java 6

Comment: no compiler compilance level is set to 1.6 explicitily. that is why i get confused. and the classes are generated? Maybe eclipse adds a parameter while compiling etc, which resolves the issue? I also added some java 1.7 or 1.8 feature to my simple main function to check whether it is really 1.6 specific and it does not get compiled.

Comment: To be fair I rarely use Eclipse (IntelliJ user), so if the compliance level is not set to a higher version then I'm out of ideas why this works in Eclipse. Either way upgrading your project should solve it for all compilers